# Some list items in RecyclerView are invisible

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a Recyclerview that takes from an arraylist of items. Some items show up in the Recycler view, but only one item shows up. I know the other items are there, but they are invisible. Here's the XML for one row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:background="#7a7a7a"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the XML for the RecyclerView Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AdminActivity"
    android:layout_margin="18dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemsRV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/itemsRV"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/deleteBtn"
        android:text="Delete"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I know that the items are there, and the app recognizes they are there, but they're just invisible for some reason. Also, I'm using LinearLayoutManager

I tried checking to see if the items just weren't being created, but that wasn't the problem. Then I created a button that deletes an item, and it deleted the invisible items before deleting the one invisible one.

[Before Deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETtkd.png)

[After Deleting One (Button has shifted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BQWa.png)

Still invisible. I tried changing the Linear Layout Manager from its default to a vertical orientation, and it still stays invisible. Honestly, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: Here's my adapter class

```
package com.trashscan.testapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class MainAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Item> posts;

    public MainAdapter(List<Item> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context c = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);

        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(itemView);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Item i = posts.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(i.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your problem is with layout_height="match_parent" in the item_row layout and it should be layout_height="wrap_content"